# Proper Format of iframe in PHP?

Tags: php, iframe

I'm trying to echo out an iframe in php like this.

```
echo
"<li><iframe src=\"http://localhost/ptb1/includes/mod_uploads/profile_pics/index.php" width="188" height="258" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; margin-top:-4px; margin-left:-4px; border:none;\"></iframe></li>";
```

Whatever I'm doing it's not working. Can someone please tell me the correct way to write this within php?

Comment: your not escaping all he quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not properly escaping the double quotes. You only escape it before the `http://` bit and all the way at the end, but not in between (which is also necessary). If you encapsulate the HTML between single quotes, you don't have to escape all the double ones. Try it like this:

```
echo '<li><iframe src="http://localhost/ptb1/includes/mod_uploads/profile_pics/index.php" width="188" height="258" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; margin-top:-4px; margin-left:-4px; border:none;"></iframe></li>';
```

Although, you're not using any variables in your string, so alternatively you can also "step out" of PHP for a bit and just use plain HTML, like:

```
<?php
// Your code starts here somehwere, now close the PHP tag
?>
<li><iframe src="http://localhost/ptb1/includes/mod_uploads/profile_pics/index.php" width="188" height="258" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; margin-top:-4px; margin-left:-4px; border:none;"></iframe></li>
<?php
// ... and continue right here
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you are only escaping the quote after `src=` and `border:none;` instead of every one?

EDIT: And @Oldskool beat me to it xD

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to display double quotes

```
<?php    
echo "<li><iframe src=\"http://localhost/ptb1/includes/mod_uploads/profile_pics/index.php\" width=\"188\" height=\"258\" scrolling=\"no\" style=\"overflow:hidden; margin-top:-4px; margin-left:-4px; border:none;\"></iframe></li>";
?>
```